# How to generate an Avro String

Tags: avro

I'm very new to Avro, going through examples online.

However I am trying to figure out something of which I can not find no example, hence I wonder if I am thinking it the wrong way.

Most of the examples I have been through are all about defining records and the schema is always of type record.

However, what I would like to do at this point, is simply serialising and deserialising a string albeit using Avro. I don't want to define any surrounding structure such as what record does. I don't want fields. Simply the bare string serialized and deserialized as Avro.

So my "Top Level Schema" would be something like `{"type": "string"}`.

From there are I am blocked, I look at the API but I don't see anything that would help me create a string and serialize it such that for record.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is correct. Not sure what you've tried, but the `avro-tools` JAR is valuable for general CLI usage.

```bash
$ alias avro-tools
avro-tools='java -jar ./workspace/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar'
$ avro-tools random --schema='{"type":"string"}' --count 1 out.avro
$ cat out.avro
Objavro.schema"string"avro.codecdeflate���cٙ��!�`�.�+N�H,/I���cٙ��!�`�.%
$ avro-tools tojson out.avro
"sdxawtd"
```

From Java itself, you'd use a `GenericData.Record`, provide it that schema, then write those records into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `DataFileWriter`

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing+and+deserializing+without+code+generation